# xml unmarshalling questions

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

Now, the xml is something like below:

```
<db>
 <type1>
   <data1>...</data1>
   <data2>...</data2>
          ...
   <data7>...</data7>
 </type1>
 <type2>
   <meta1>...</meta1>
   <meta2>...</meta2>
          ...
   <meta9>...</meta9>
 </type2>
.....
</db>
```

This xml just contains several type1 and type2 information. I hope to unmarshall this xml file and just need the information data1,data3,data5 of type1 and meta1, meta4, meta6 of type2.

For type1, every type1 contains data1, data3 and data5, but may not contains data2,data4,data6, data7.

For type2,every type1 contains meta1, meta4 and meta6, but may not contains meta2,meta3,meta5, meta7,meta8,meta9.
I have three questions:

1. How can I deal with two types in this xml file? define two class?
2. I don't know how to solve the problem that data2,data4,data6, data7 may not appear in this xml file.
3. Do I need two define two list to save the result? because there are many tags like type1 and type2.

Can anyone give me some link to learn? I find a lot, but they are not helpful. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to *unmarshall*, that means map into specific Java classes, in which case `type1` and `type2` would be different classes.

If you want something more dynamic, where `type1` and `type2` are not actual Java classes, then you're talking about *parsing*, not unmarshalling, in which case you should look at DOM or StAX.

For marshalling, you could specify something like this (getters and setters left out for brevity):

```
@XmlRootElement(name="db")
public class Db {
    @XmlElement(required=true) private Type1 type1;
    @XmlElement(required=true) private Type2 type2;
}

public class Type1 {
    @XmlElement(required=true ) private String data1;
    @XmlElement(required=false) private String data2;
    @XmlElement(required=true ) private String data3;
    @XmlElement(required=false) private String data4;
    @XmlElement(required=true ) private String data5;
    @XmlElement(required=false) private String data6;
    @XmlElement(required=false) private String data7;
}

public class Type2 {
    @XmlElement(required=true ) private String meta1;
    @XmlElement(required=false) private String meta2;
    @XmlElement(required=false) private String meta3;
    @XmlElement(required=true ) private String meta4;
    @XmlElement(required=false) private String meta5;
    @XmlElement(required=true ) private String meta6;
    @XmlElement(required=false) private String meta7;
    @XmlElement(required=false) private String meta8;
    @XmlElement(required=false) private String meta9;
}
```

Running `schemagen` on that would produce the following XSD file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="db" type="db"/>

  <xs:complexType name="db">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="type1" type="type1"/>
      <xs:element name="type2" type="type2"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="type1">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="data1" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="data2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="data3" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="data4" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="data5" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="data6" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="data7" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="type2">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="meta1" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="meta2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="meta3" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="meta4" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="meta5" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="meta6" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="meta7" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="meta8" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="meta9" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```